# Putting an almost completed and highly relevant qualification on resume

Tags: resume

I am applying for an entry-level position that favours having a certain qualification.

This qualification is comprised of several classroom/practical units and a work experience component. I have completed all the taught units, but am still finishing my work experience (it is very near completion) - how would I (if I even should) display this on my resume?

How I'm displaying it currently:

**QUALIFICATION NAME**
Completed all teaching units, currently completing vocational placement at X, expected completion by ...

Comment: Leave out the word "expected" and it is perfect. (Everything is "expected" - it is "expected" that the sun will rise tomorrow, but it may not.  Delete that word!)

Comment: @Fattie There is some value in providing an ETA for completion - it doesn't leave the employer wondering if the completion of the qualification will be done in a week or  year, and this could be a decision-altering factor.

Comment: Hi @520 - absolutely.   But leave out the specific word "expected".  (Everything ever stated, is "expected".)  Hence, write: "Completion 3/3/2019".  Do not write "Completion expected: 3/3/2019."  Sorry if I was not clear.  Literally delete the single word "expected".

Comment: @Fattie while I take your point, the usual language of CVs is to talk about the past tense, what the person *has* done, where the notion of expectations are a moot point. In the odd sentence talking about the future, it is appropriate to use the word 'expected' to signify a) that it hasn't happened yet, and b) that it is a real and current thing that is being progressed and not a pipe-dream.

Comment: @Fattie why "expected" shouldn't be used: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expect?q=Expect - "to think or believe something will happen".  NOTE "think" and "belive" which conveys it to be a probable outcome but NOT a 100% certain result. You want to show confidence and certainty, thus removing "expected" is preferred.

Comment: exactly as @DigitalBlade969 says

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This makes perfect sense for someone without a lot of experience on their resume.

The format that you have in mind is appropriate too. As long as you clearly label it as an "Expected Completion Date", you are being completely up front about the state of this qualification.